# Which cloud support flexible CPU/Memory upgrade and downgrade on the same instance?

Tags: cloud, wpml

[image]

I have a WooCommerce website with WPML multi language plugins.  When I try to batch update products, the CPU soar to 100%. But once updating complete, the CPU drop back to around 15%.

At this moment, I am on Digital Ocean, CPU optimised, 4GB memory and 2CPUs.

Do you know a cloud provide, who can flexible upgrade and downgrade the CPU on the same instance/server, without the need to move data and configurations to another server?

I know all of them support upgrade.
Anyone support downgrade?

Ps.  I am contacting with WPML as well, to see if there is anything can be done to reduce CPU surging.

Answer (score 0):

I found that there is actually a Resize CPU / Memory section. I can upgrade and downgrade it.  I should have known this earlier.  Just in case anyone who has the same question, here is the screenshot:

[image: Change CPU/Memory]